# Fast way to get a position of combination (without repetitions)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, computational-mathematics

*This question has an inverse: [(Fast way to) Get a combination given its position in (reverse-)lexicographic order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368526/fast-way-to-get-a-combination-given-its-position-in-reverse-lexicographic-or)*

---

**What would be the most efficient way to `translate` a combination of $k$-tuple into its *positions* within the $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)$ combinations?**
I need this to be fast for combinations of $\left(\!\!\binom{70}{7}\!\!\right)$ order of magnitude - very large, but not exceeding 2 billion (fits into `int32` maximum value).

Below is an example of $\left(\!\!\binom{6}{3}\!\!\right)$, where the aim is to *quickly* translate `(a, d, f)` tuple to value `9`, while in the real problem $k$ ranges between 5 and 8.

$$\begin{array}
{cccccc|c}
a&b&c&d&e&f&^{combination}/_{sort\_order}&
\\\hline
x&x&x& & & &1\\
x&x& &x& & &2\\
x&x& & &x& &3\\
x&x& & & &x&4\\
x& &x&x& & &5\\
x& &x& &x& &6\\
x& &x& & &x&7\\
x& & &x&x& &8\\
x& & &x& &x&9\\
x& & & &x&x&10\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
 & & &x&x&x&20\\
\end{array}$$

I know that I could pre-calculate all the combinations and reverse the lookup dictionary. However, such dictionary would not be efficient in terms of memory usage. Therefore I am looking for either calculation-based approach, or a more efficient data structure to perform this mapping.

Comment: How efficient does it need to be with respect to the length of the $k$-tuples? can it be cuadratic over $k$?

Comment: @dREaM:  It can be quadratic. However, as indicated, I am looking for best efficiency in the ranges for $5 < k < 7$ and $50 < n < 70$.

Comment: This question has been asked before multiple times on both this website and StackOverflow; one of the existing answers may suit you. (That's assuming that your $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)$ is just an odd way of writing $\binom{n}{k}$ because I don't know what else it could mean.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: could you please point to those duplicates.

Comment: @van E.g. on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143142/compute-rank-of-a-combination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307222/how-to-calculate-the-index-lexicographical-order-when-the-combination-is-given (and many others). On this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349924/function-mapping-combinations-to-natural-numbers (and many others). On Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system Terms to search for are "(ranking|indexing) combinations", also "combinadics", and names of those WP articles.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Let us denote your tuple [a b c] as [1 1 1 0 0 0] and so on.

Define $\binom{n}{r}=0$ for $n<r$

For your tuple: $[a d f] = [1 0 0 1 0 1]$
$$P = 1\cdot \binom{0}{1}+0\cdot \binom{1}{1}+0\cdot \binom{2}{1}+1\cdot \binom{3}{2}+0\cdot\binom{4}{2}+1\cdot\binom{5}{3} + 1$$
$$P=0 + 0 +0 +3+0+10+0+1 = 14$$

**General Algorithm:**

- Calculate the position value of each binary digit using $\binom{n}{r}$
- Take $n$ as position of the digit from left, for leftmost digit $n=0$.
- Write $r$ for each position as the number of 'ONES' counted from left, including the one at current position.

**Example-1: [a b c] = [1 1 1 0 0 0]**

Calculate the position of the tuple as sum:
$$P = 1\cdot \binom{0}{1}+1\cdot \binom{1}{2}+1\cdot \binom{2}{3}+0\cdot \binom{3}{3}+0\cdot\binom{4}{3}+0\cdot\binom{5}{3} + 1$$
$$P=0 + 0 +0 +0+0+0+0+1 = 1$$

**Example-2: [d e f] = [0 0 0 1 1 1]**
$$P = 0\cdot \binom{0}{0}+0\cdot \binom{1}{0}+0\cdot \binom{2}{0}+1\cdot \binom{3}{1}+1\cdot\binom{4}{2}+1\cdot\binom{5}{3} + 1$$
$$S=0+0+0+3+6+10+1=20$$

The lone ONE is added because you are not starting at zero.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising for implementation. Let me check the performance I get out of it? Any ideas on the reverse *lookup*?

Comment: Denoting the zero-based indices of the 1s with $i_0,\ldots,i_{k-1}$, this answer computes $1+\sum_{r=1}^k\binom{i_{r-1}}{r}$. This means that the ordering is reverse-lexicographic as in my answer, not lexicographic as in the question. Needless to say, I like it because it is simpler.

Comment: Reverse lookup would be same thing backwards.

Comment: @ccorn If the indexing is started from right instead of left side, the ordering would be lexicographic.

Comment: @Galaxy: What do you mean by the *same thing backwards*? How would I get from `9` to `(a, d, f)` or `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`?

Comment: @van Perhaps you can ask a new question.

Comment: Just did at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363239. Thank you.

Comment: @van added complimentary question of reverse problem at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368526/fast-way-to-get-a-combination-given-its-position-in-reverse-lexicographic-or/1368570#1368570

Answer (score 6):

I'll relabel your `(a,d,f)` to `(1,4,6)` and denote it by $(i_1,i_2,i_3)$ so we can calculate with it.

Start at index $\binom nk$. Moving the $k$-th entry to the left by $1$ reduces the index by $1=\binom{n-j}0$. Moving the $(k-1)$-th entry to the left from $j$ to $j-1$ reduces the index by $n-j=\binom{n-j}1$. Generally, moving the $(k-m)$-th entry to the left from $j$ to $j-1$ reduces the index by $\binom{n-j}m$. Thus the index is

$$
\binom nk-\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\;\sum_{j=i_{k-m}+1}^{n-m}\binom{n-j}m\;.
$$

You can easily precalculate the inner sums so that you can look them up using $m$ and $i_{k-m}$, so you just need to add up the $k$ terms in the sum over $m$ to get the index.

*P.S.:* That was unnecessarily complicated; the inner sum simplifies, and the result is

$$
\binom nk-\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\binom{n-i_{k-m}}{m+1}\;.
$$

You can probably derive that more directly, but since you're perhaps just interested in a practical result and not the most elegant way of deriving it, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: And if you care to say what you need this for, I'd be interested :-)

Comment: I was able to use this solution for my problem.  In my case I am calculating poker hands and probabilities and saving the results to a database.  I originally created a database id via simple concatination but changing to a 1-based bijective id will be much better in the long run.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Your tuple ordering is lexicographic and your to-be-computed position
is one-based, as are the symbol codes for $a,b,\ldots$ used in @joriki's answer;
but for the sake of simplicity I will use reverse-lexicographic ordering
and zero-based positions and letter codes.
Conversion is done by replacing @joriki's $(i_1,\ldots,i_k)$
with $(n-i_k,\ldots,n-i_1)$
and replacing the position resulting from my formula with its distance to
$\binom{n}{k}$.
The result below is thus consistent with @joriki's formula.

I have used such computations for compression of multi-indices
into (skew-)symmetric tensors; therefore I borrow some vocabulary from that
domain.

Let us define a *$k$-index* to be
a $k$-tuple of strictly increasing nonnegative integers.
You may have to sort accordingly and to disallow duplicate entries.

$k$-indices can be totally ordered in a reverse-lexicographic manner:
Sorting is done by the last element,
in case of equality by the next-to-last element, and so on.

For a $k$-index $I$, let us define its *position* (or *compressed index*)
$\operatorname{ordx}(I)$ as the number of $k$-indices
that are reverse-lexicographically smaller than $I$.

Note that $\operatorname{ordx}(I) = 0$
for the smallest $k$-index $I=(0,\ldots,k-1)$.

We need a notation for truncated tuples.
Denoting $I = (i_0,\ldots,i_{k-1})$,
let $I_m = (i_0,\ldots,i_{k-m-1})$ for integer $m$ with $0\leq m<k$.
That is $I$ with the last $m$ elements chopped off.

Now a $k$-index $J=(j_0,\ldots,j_{k-1})$ is
reverse-lexicographically smaller than $I$ if and only if

- $j_{k-1} < i_{k-1}$;
  there are $\binom{i_{k-1}}{k}$ such $k$-indices; or
- $k>1$, and $j_{k-1} = i_{k-1}$,
  and $J_1$ is reverse-lexicographically smaller than $I_1$.
  This condition involves a comparison of $(k-1)$-indices.

Proceeding by induction, we arrive at the formula

$$\operatorname{ordx}(I) = \sum_{r=1}^k\binom{i_{r-1}}{r}$$

It is worth noting that this formula does not depend on the upper bound $n$
for the index elements.

The binomial coefficient values can be computed on the fly
by initializing and updating a segment of Pascal's triangle.
Define
$$b_{j}^{(r)} = \binom{j+r}{r} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $r=0$ or $j=0$} \\
b_{j}^{(r-1)} + b_{j-1}^{(r)} & \text{if $r>0$ and $j>0$}
\end{cases}$$
So we just need to initialize and update an array
$$B^{(r)} = \left(b_0^{(r)},\ldots,b_{i_{k-1}-k}^{(r)}\right)$$
In practice, we prepend a $0$ to that array in order to account
for the case $i_{r-1} = r-1$ which requires a zero binomial coefficient.

In Python (which uses zero-based indices and half-open ranges):

```
def ordx(idx):
    """
    Turns a multi-index of strictly increasing nonnegative integers
    into a 1-dimensional zero-based index.
    """
    s = 0
    b = [0] + [1] * (idx[-1] + 1 - len(idx))    # [0, 1, 1, ...]
    for r,i in enumerate(idx):      # (0,idx[0]), (1,idx[1]), ...
        for j in xrange(2, len(b)): # 2, ..., len(b)-1
            b[j] += b[j-1]          # binomial(j+r, r+1)
        s += b[i - r]
    return s
```

**Besides:**
If you want to allow duplicate tuple elements, you can transform that
problem by adding to each element $i_r$ the sub-index $r$ and
computing `ordx` for the modified tuple which now has strict increments.
For that use case, the code above gets simplified a bit:

```
def ords(idx):
    """
    Turns a multi-index of nondecreasing nonnegative integers
    into a 1-dimensional zero-based index.
    """
    s = 0
    b = [0] + [1] * idx[-1]         # [0, 1, 1, ..., 1]
    for i in idx:
        for j in xrange(2, len(b)): # 2, ..., len(b)-1 = idx[-1]
            b[j] += b[j-1]
        s += b[i]
    return s
```

This computes
$$\operatorname{ords}(I) = \sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\binom{i_r + r}{r+1}$$
Such a function `ords` could be used for compressing a sorted multi-index
for totally symmetric tensors to a flat index that removes redundancy.

**Update:**
The above algorithms are simple, but need to update an array of binomial
coefficients for each index element.
Consequently, running the above `ords` needs $k\,i_{k-1}$ additions
and an array `b` of length $i_{k-1}+1$.
For `ordx` replace $i_{k-1}$ with $i_{k-1}-k+1$.
We can reduce the operation count and memory usage by computing
each needed binomial coefficient directly from the previous one.
This requires a sequence of multiplications and divisions instead
of just additions, but it reduces binomial bookkeeping to one scalar variable
and keeps total `ords` operation count at $\operatorname{O}(k+i_{k-1})$.
Correspondingly, `ordx` operation count is $\operatorname{O}(i_{k-1})$.
Here is a sample Python implementation of the optimized $\operatorname{ordx}$
(with `//` denoting integer division):

```
def ordx_opt(idx):
    """
    Turns a multi-index of strictly increasing nonnegative integers
    into a 1-dimensional zero-based index.
    """
    s = 0
    j = 1
    b = 1
    for r,i in enumerate(idx):  # (0,idx[0]), (1,idx[1]), ...
        if i == r: continue     # skipping terms with zero binomial coeff
        # b == binomial(j+r-1, r), update to j == i - r
        while j < i - r:
            b *= j + r
            b //= j
            j += 1
        # b == binomial(i-1, r), update to binomial(i, r+1)
        b *= i
        b //= r + 1
        s += b
    return s
```

And the corresponding optimized $\operatorname{ords}$:

```
def ords_opt(idx):
    """
    Turns a multi-index of nondecreasing nonnegative integers
    into a 1-dimensional zero-based index.
    """
    s = 0
    j = 1
    b = 1
    for r,i in enumerate(idx):
        if i == 0: continue     # skipping terms with zero binomial coeff
        # b == binomial(j+r-1, r), update to j == i
        while j < i:
            b *= j + r
            b //= j
            j += 1
        # b == binomial(i+r-1, r), update to binomial(i+r, r+1)
        b *= i + r
        b //= r + 1
        s += b
    return s
```

Comment: Thank you, even the implementation is there. Let me check the performance I get out of it. Any ideas on the reverse *lookup*?

Comment: Regarding the reverse lookup, better make that another question. Answers to that will probably take a significant amount of space. Of course, the induced ordering matters; so the answer will depend on whether you want lexicographic or reverse-lexicographic ordering.

Comment: Thank you. I can well imagine the reverse would indeed require longer explanations. But the ordering does not matter, as long as one to one mapping can be established. On topic of performance: computational performance is of higher importance. In this respect, it looks like storing pre-calculated values, and require only sums during *run* is both memory and CPU efficient.

Comment: If you compile to machine code, memory accesses (including access to lookup tables) are nowadays much slower than computations with values in registers, with the possible exception of integer divisions. I have added code that uses muls and divs but no extra arrays and therefore reduces memory bottlenecks. Might be worth a try.

Comment: One potential problem with the multiplications and divisions is the risk of intermediate overflow. You may need to check if you have enough bits to afford the extra factor (less than $n$) which the code then divides out.

Comment: From my tests in `python` so far, pre-calculating and storing in memory a small part of the Pascal triangles required for this computation produces the best result. I am yet to try both of your *computational* version using `Cython` or `numba` and will let you know my finding. In the meantime, I asked the inverse question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363239

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question and was pointed here.  I was able to use joriki's solution, slightly tweaked, and came up with the following C# code:

```
public int GetCombID(List<int> comb, int max = 51)
{
    UInt64 id = nCr(max + 1, comb.Count);            
    for (int i = 0; i < comb.Count; i++)
        id -= nCr(max - comb[i], comb.Count - i);
    return (int)id;
}
```

To reverse the process I use the following:

```
public List<int> GetCombFromID(int id, int combLength = 2,  int max = 51)
{
    List<int> comb = new List<int>(combLength);
    var tId = nCr(max + 1, combLength) - (UInt64)id;
    for(int i = combLength; i > 0; i--)
    {
        UInt64 tVal = 0;
        bool done = false;
        int pos = 0;
        while(!done)
        {
            var t = nCr(max - pos, i);
            if (t <= tId)
            {
                tVal = t;
                done = true;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        tId -= tVal;
        comb.Add(pos - 1);
    }

    return comb;
}
```

I post this now as a reference for others in the future.

Comment: The function for reversing the process does not work for ids towards the end although it works for some low indices.

Comment: @AAsk Can you provide a counter example?  I've used this formula quite a bit and have yet to see any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

use this function very efficient, but read the comments first before using it to know how it works

```
def getCombRep(nValue, rValue, term):

    '''
    this function return a number whose binary representation equals nth combination given
    n , r, t = nValue, rValue, nthTerm or term
    view combination as selection of element from a set,
    element can either be selected or not
    so there is two options, selected and not selected
    these options can be represented in binary form, selected be 1 and not selected be 0
    consider this simple set of element [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
    let us choose six element from this set, C(10,6) ---> C(n,r)
    if 11011011 is our nth selection in binary form, then selected set will be [c, d, f, g, i, j] 
    our binary selection will always contain number of 1s equal to r, r equals 6 in our example set
    the length of our binary selection is not equal to number of element in the set,
    append leading zeros until length equals number of element, 0011011011
    or start selection from right to left of the set
    let us follow the following steps in detail to reach our goal
    '''

    #calcutate the biggest nth combination, as limit
    num = math.factorial(nValue)
    den = math.factorial(nValue - rValue) * math.factorial(rValue)
    limit = num // den
    # check if the limit exceeded, if exceeded take the reminder
    reminder = term % (limit + 1)
    #since we are counting nth permutation from 1, if reminder is zero, increment to one
    if reminder == 0:
        reminder += 1
    # set term equals reminder
    term = reminder

    combList = []
    nthTerm = term

    '''
    STEP 1: CONVERT nthTERM GIVEN IN COMBINATION REPRESENTATION.
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    STEPS:
        1. let r be the number of element to be choosen, and n the number of element in the set
        2. find x in range 0 to n such that C(r+x,x) is equal to or is the first smallest from term given
           if no such C(r+x,x)  exist in this range go to step 6
        3. append, x + r and x as pair, use list, for our case combList is used
        4. calculate the difference btn term and C(r+x,x) calculated ie term - C(r+x,x)
        5. update the term to be the difference calculated
        6. drop the value of r by one ie r - 1
        7. repeat step 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 until term equals zero
    so now our combination representation of nthterm will look like this
        x1Cr + x2Cr-1 + x3Cr-2 + ... + xnCo ( may not contain all terms)
    '''
    #looping all possible r in descending order(step 1 and 6)
    for r in range(rValue, 0, -1):
        #looping all possible x in ascending order (step 2)
        for x in range(nValue):
            #calculate xCr
            num = math.factorial(r + x)
            den = math.factorial(x) * math.factorial(r)
            ncr = num // den
            #test if xCr exceed the nth term 
            #if true, then the preious term is either first smallest of equals to nth term
            if(ncr > nthTerm):
                #calculate x-1Cr, previous term (step 2)
                num = math.factorial(r + x - 1)
                den = math.factorial(x -1) * math.factorial(r)
                ncr = num // den
                # values calculated 
                combList.append([r + x - 1, x - 1])
                #update term to be the difference
                nthTerm = nthTerm - ncr
                #break out of x loop for next step
                break
        # if in between the loop term drop to zero, then break out of r loop
        if nthTerm == 0:
            break
    '''
    STEP 2: CONVERT COMBINATION REPRESENTATION TO COMBINATION NUMBER
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    here combination number is the number whose binary number represent nth combination
    this number contain exactly 1s equals to number of element to be selected from list given

    TERMS:
        1. ostep:: is outside step(o - step) that increases the binary digit by one, 
                   is the first C(n,r) value in the combination representation of the nth term
                eg 111111 ---> 1011111, 1111110--->10011111, number of digit increase by one
        2. istep:: is inside step (i - step) that shift 1s inside a binary number one step to the left of binary digit
                   are intermediate C(n,r) values in the combination representation
                   isteps occurs if there is more than 2 steps to make, and they are intermediate steps btn o and f steps
                eg 10011111 ---> 10101111, 10000111 --->10001011, number of digits remain the same
        3. svalue:: is stepping value and is the difference between first term of the current step 
                    and last term of previous step, if there is only one step to make, no svalue should be added,
                    because we are not stapping to the next step, so the final step always does not have svalue
                    eg 1011111 - 111111 = 95 - 63 = 32
        3. fstep:: this is equal to final step(f - step), all o and i steps can be fsteps
                   if only ostep exist, there is no i or f steps, even if there is only one step
                   fstep occurs if there is more than one step to make
                   and is the final step
    EXPlANATION:
        consider this simple set of element [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
        Let us choose four element from a set, the last four element will be choosen first, 0000001111
        then 0000010111, 0000011011, 0000011101, 0000011110, 0000100111, and so one.
        all bit are shifted to the left before the next ostep occured
        can we engineer the pattern here?

        1                 1111         15
        2                10111         23
        3                11011         27
        4                11101         29
        5                11110         30
        6               100111         39
        7               101011         43
        8               101101         45
        9               101110         46

        without appending zeros

        take this point for simplicity:
        1. nth ostep occurs at ((2^r - 1)*(2^k)) + ((2^(r - 1)) + (2^k - 1))
           ((2^r - 1)*(2^k)) ---> is the last term of the previous ostep, from example are 1 and 5
           ((2^(r - 1)) + (2^k - 1)) ---> is svalue when added to last term, new ostep is formed
           where k is the nth step,  1 <= k <= n - r, when r = 4, and n = 10, there are 6 0steps
           k is increasing by one while r is decreasing by one
        2. nth istep occurs at ((2^(r - x) - 1) * (2^r - 1)) + ((2^(r - 1 - x)) + (2**r - 1)) + (constant ostep)
           ((2^(r - x) - 1) * (2^r - 1))--> last term of previous istep, eg 3 and 7 (check isteps)
           (2^r - 1)) + ((2^(r - 1 - x)) --> is svalue for moving to the next istep
           where k is the nth step,  1 <= k <= n - r - 1, when r = 4, and n = 10, there are 5 0steps
           k is increasing by one while r is decreasing by one
        3. if ther is only one step, this step is ostep, and if there is more than one, 
           the final step is fstep, if there are two steps no istep2 exist
        4. fstep is either ostep or istep but no steping value present, because it is the final step 

    RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN STEPS AND COMBINATION REPRESENTATION.

    We have combination representation in the list already, in form of [n, r], 
    the length of the list represent the number steps, ostep-->isteps-->fstep, to make
    only the r's are used, n's are like waste now
    r is always equals to k in our formulas 
    in every step formula there are two terms, let say a and g
        (2^r -1)*(2^k) + (2^(r - 1)) + (2^k - 1) --> (a) * (2^k) + (g) + (2^k -1)
        (2^(r - x) - 1) * (2^r - 1)) + ((2^(r - 1 - x)) + (2^r - 1)) + (constant ostep) 
        -->((a) * (2^r - 1)) + ((g) + (2^r - 1)) + (constant ostep)
    now you know a and g,
    in every step, g is halved and a get reduced by g ie a = a - g

    '''
    # variable to store the number we are going to calculate
    number = 0
    #looping all combination representation from the combList
    for x in range(len(combList)):
        #a g and r are evaluated here
        a, g, r = (2**(rValue - x) - 1), (2**(rValue - 1 -x)), combList[x][1]

        #this if the ostep as final step, svalue is omitted 
        if x == 0 and len(combList) == 1:
            p = (a * 2**r)
            number += p
        #this is the ostep with svalue
        if x == 0 and len(combList) > 1:
            p = (a * 2**r) + (g) + (2**r -1)
            number += p
        #this is the final step, no svalue
        if x == len(combList) - 1 and len(combList) > 1:
            p = (a * (2**r - 1))
            number += p
            #break out of loop coz it is the final step
            break

        #this is the istep
        if x > 0 and x < len(combList) - 1:
            p = (a * (2**r - 1)) + (g) + (2**r - 1)
            number += p
    return number
```